# Are HSE participants allowed to denigrate Hindu scripture in their own words (not citing scriptural material)?

Tags: discussion, scripture

[What is the story of Vishnu killing sage Bhrighu's wife Kavyamata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-is-the-story-of-vishnu-killing-sage-bhrighus-wife-kavyamata)

the user writes:

> Unfortunately, the Devi Bhagavatam is widely regarded as not being an authentic Hindu scripture; it's purportedly an Upapurana (minor Purana), but it's not mentioned in the canonical lists  of Upapuranas given in the Mahapuranas."

The link he cites leads to Wikipedia.

May we have a ruling on this, please?

Comment: Without sources, it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: It used to happen a lot in the past but we have successfully put a stop to it. Does not happen now.

Comment: will older material like this stay around for ever?

Comment: Not sure if mods will decide for removing all such sentences from all old posts or not but you should be happy that it won't be allowed to happen now @SK

Comment: this kind of content will not stop appearing at HSE.  Can we expect prompt action in the future when it is flagged @rickross ?

Comment: Used to be done by one user only and it has stopped occurring now .. yes I think we can expect prompt actions .. the flags that I raise are handled reasonably quick these days .. there was a time (during 2020) when there used to be delays in handling flags due inactivity of the mods but that has been sorted out now @SK